# Using a UITableView in Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sprite-kit

I'm currently having an issue. I'm creating a game and I want to be able to use a UITableView to show data (Like levels). However, I'm using strictly SpriteKit and can't seem to get the UITableView and SpritKit to work.

I tried creating a variable in my 'GameScene' class (which is an SKScene) called 'gameTableView' and its value set to a class I made called 'GameRoomTableView'.

```
var gameTableView = GameRoomTableView()
```

The class had the value of 'UITableView' (notice that I did not set it to UITableViewController).

```
class GameRoomTableView: UITableView {
}
```

I was able to add the tableView as a subview of my SKView. I did this in my 'DidMoveToView' function that's inside my GameScene class. In which got the view to show.

```
self.scene?.view?.addSubview(gameRoomTableView)
```

However, I do not know how to change things like the number of sections and how to add cells.The class won't let me access those type of things unless it's a viewController and with that I'd need an actual ViewController to get it to work. I've seen many games use tableViews but I'm not sure how they got it to work, haha.

Please don't hesitate to tell me what I'm doing wrong and if you know of a better way of going about this. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I've never tried adding a `UITableView` to a `SpriteKitScene`, but are you sure you can't just make the class conform to the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`? I'm not saying this WILL work, but I wrote some example code where I did just that and it doesn't show any errors

Comment: Just ovelay a UITableView on top of the same same space as SpriteKitScene and then change the .alpha to show/hide it?

Comment: One tragic part of SpriteKit is its UI premise/promise vs reality. Using AutoLayout and UIViews layered on top of a SpriteKit game should permit creating level selectors with ease. That nobody seems to have ever done it, and that there's no sample code or other demonstrations available suggests a few things. 1. few people use SpriteKit. 2. Of those that do, it's not been done. because a) Apple doesn't show how to do it with ease and/or b) it's got rubbish performance and/or c) getting it done is like jumping through gyroscopically rotating flaming hoops in a varying gravity environment

Comment: I'm gonna have to agree with Confused. For now, I'll be using either making my own way of doing it in SpriteKit or just using UIKit

Comment: Likely that mixing SpriteKit and UIKit UI elements was not the idea how things should be done when it comes to SpriteKit games. For example, when transitioning between scenes, all UIKit elements should be manually removed (deallocated, or at least hidden) which can be messy on bigger projects. I mean it is doable, but personally I avoid it. Hopefully Apple engeeners will add more of UIKit-like useful elements into SpriteKit framework.

Comment: I'm definitely okay with @Confused, use SpriteKit is already a titanic task, even using the elements UIKit becomes quite daunting. There isn't sufficient documentation and many class have too many private properties inaccessible that make customization sometimes impossible. As said by Whirlwind I hope one day Apple does something to help developers and game developers.

Comment: @Nickolans I'm in the middle of researching how to make my own adaptive and responsive UI manager with SK Physics doing the heavy lifting. If you want to chat more about this... and discuss it with a couple of others considering this approach, I think we could find somewhere off/outside this place. But don't know where.

Comment: I found that Alessandro Ornano's answer fixed my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually I don't prefer subclass the `UITableView` as you doing, I prefer to use the `UITableView` delegate and datasource directly to my `SKScene` class to control both table specs and data to my game code.

But probably you have your personal scheme so I make an example to you follow your request:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
class GameRoomTableView: UITableView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var items: [String] = ["Player1", "Player2", "Player3"]
    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Section \(section)"
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
}
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var gameTableView = GameRoomTableView()
    private var label : SKLabelNode?
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.label = self.childNode(withName: "//helloLabel") as? SKLabelNode
        if let label = self.label {
            label.alpha = 0.0
            label.run(SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 2.0))
        }
        // Table setup
        gameTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        gameTableView.frame=CGRect(x:20,y:50,width:280,height:200)
        self.scene?.view?.addSubview(gameTableView)
        gameTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: This worked flawlessly and is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Two years later this still works as expected.  Thanks!